# Interleaved PWM Generator for DC-DC Converter

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, dc-dc-converter

I have an PWM signal ready from opamp which has an switching frequency around 10KHz what can be done to obtain an interleaved version (T/2 Delayed version) of this signal

FYI,
I have used sawtooth wave(i generated this with IC555) and an dc control voltage as my requirement was trailing edge modulated wave with duty cycle of 0-100%

Comment: This is phrased like a homework question. Could you share what work you have done towards the goal?

Comment: I have Found a way to generate the trailing edge with opamp with one of its input as saw tooth which is generated from an ic555 subcircuit but i have to find a way to generate the interleaved version of the output